# Non-Formal Applications: Higman and Kruskal

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, applications, infinite-sequences

After looking through many papers, I noticed that most of the discussions and proofs for Higman's Lemma and Kruskal's Tree Theorem only have formal applications in set theory, logic, and type theory. What are some non-formal applications for Higman's Lemma and/or Kruskal's Tree Theorem?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "informal". Some people might define math as the study of formal structures, so... Can you give an example of what you mean by an "informal application", not related to the theorems mentioned in your question?

Comment: @ToddTrimble What I mean is like other fields of mathematics like geometry or Ramsey Theory, etc.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the correctness proof of the Knuth-Bendix completion algorithm uses Kruskal's theorem.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Bendix_completion_algorithm
- http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~jean/kruskal.pdf

Comment: How so? Can you show me?

Answer (score 3):

Unsurprisingly, there are various ways in which Higman's lemma is used in the context of Gröbner bases. One interesting recent example : http://www.msri.org/people/members/chillar/files/HS-MonoidGBFiniteness.pdf

Comment: Ah. Quite interesting. I will have to learn some ring theory before attempting to truly understand this paper.